# Power BI Report Server - Auto refresh of data in report from Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

Is it possible to do an automatic refresh of data in a report that is linked to a SharePoint list / library on-premise? I mean without using a scheduled refresh

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your way of thinking. An automatic refresh works BECAUSE it is scheduled. What would trigger the "automatic" refresh in your world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For on-premises SharePoint data you need the Data Gateway and automatic refresh of that data can only be achieved by a scheduled refresh set up in the Gateway.